# Rails/JQuery: Hide submit button unless at least 1 checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to hide the submit in a form button unless at least one of the checkboxes is selected.
Here is a sample of my view

```
<div class="ck-button">
    <label class="checklabel">
        <%= f.check_box :swim , class:"activityCK" %><span>swim</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="ck-button">
    <label class="checklabel">
        <%= f.check_box :spin , class:"activityCK" %><span>spin</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="ck-button">
    <label class="checklabel">
        <%= f.check_box :climb , class:"activityCK" %><span>climb</span>
    </label>
</div>

<%= f.submit 'SPOT ME!', class:"btn btn-danger bt-lg submit" %>
```

I found this code from another user (I already confirmed that it loads correctly)

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen to `change` event of the checkboxes rather than the `click` event, and then combine the `:checked` pseudo-class with the `.length` property in order to determine if there are any checked checkboxes.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yrue0yfn/)

```
$(':checkbox').on('change', function () {
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', !$(':checkbox:checked').length);
}).change();
```

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function () {
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', !$(':checkbox:checked').length);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ck-button">
    <label class="checklabel">
        <input type="checkbox"><span>swim</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="ck-button">
    <label class="checklabel">
        <input type="checkbox"><span>spin</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="ck-button">
    <label class="checklabel">
        <input type="checkbox"><span>climb</span>
    </label>
</div>

<input type="submit" value='SPOT ME!' class="btn btn-danger bt-lg submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `prop()` instead of `attr()`.